Unsure about a step regarding dimensions of nullspace and range in a proof
A proof I am following makes a claim, but I'm unsure about how to arrive at that claim.
Context
$t$ is a transformation on $\mathbb{C}^n$, $\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of $t$, $W$ is the range of the transformation $t - \lambda_1$ and has dimension $r$ (ie. $W = \mathscr{R}(t - \lambda_1))$, and lastly we are given that $\text{dim}(W \cap \mathscr{N}(t - \lambda_1) ) = q$
Question
The proof states that because $\text{dim}(W \cap \mathscr{N}(t - \lambda_1) ) = q$ and $\text{dim}(W) = r$, then there must exist some subspace $Y \subseteq \mathscr{N}(t - \lambda_1)$ with dimension $r - q$ and such that $Y \cap W = \{0\}$. It seems to me that the proof is implicitly taking that $\text{dim}(\mathscr{N}(t - \lambda_1)) = r$, but I'm not sure why the dimension of the nullspace should equal the dimension of the range $W$. I could understand if the $Y$ was a subspace of $W$, as then the $Y$ and $W \cap \mathscr{N}(t - \lambda_1)$ could form a direct sum to $W$, but I can't see why it must be a subspace of $\mathscr{N}(t - \lambda_1)$ — what am I missing?

Whenever you have two subspaces, $S_1\subset S_2$, there is a complementary subspace $S$ such that $S_2=S_1\oplus S$ (just take the subspace generated by the vectors you have to adjoin a basis of $S_1$ to get a basis of $S_2$). Given that the sum is direct,
$$
\textrm{dim}\,S_1+\textrm{dim}\,S=\textrm{dim}\,S_2
$$
Now, apply this fact to the subspaces $S_1=W\cap\mathcal{N}(t-\lambda_1)$ and $S_2=W$.

In this case, wouldn't the $S$ then be a subspace of $W$ and not $\mathscr{N}(t - \lambda_1)$? If we take $S$ to be the subspace generated by the vectors we need to adjoin to an $S_1$ basis to get an $S_2$ basis, then the basis of $S$ would comprise of those vectors in $W$ that are not in $\mathscr{N}(t - \lambda_1)$, and thus $S$ would be a subspace of $W$ instead of $\mathscr{N}(t - \lambda_1)$. Am I correct in saying this?

Yes, you are correct. That is probably a typo. Just make sure the rest of the proof is consistent when the typo is corrected.

It must be $Y\subset W$ such that $Y\cap\mathcal{N}(t-\lambda_1)={0}$.

The next part of the proof relies on the fact that $(t - \lambda_1)y = 0$ for $y \in Y$ however, so it seems this isn't a typo and $Y$ is a subspace of the nullspace — the only angle I see in which this makes sense is if $\text{dim}(\mathscr{N}(t - \lambda_1)) = \text{dim}(W) = r$, but not sure how to justify this equality

UPDATE: it seems the typo was in the dimension of $Y$ — using rank-nullity and direct sum we can get that the dimension of $Y$ is $n - r - q$ (instead of just $r - q$) which both makes more sense and allows the rest of the proof to work; will close this question now.
